# ffmpeg png to gif losing first half of frame list with fifo filter

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, image-processing

Can anybody suggest a solution to (or at least a cause for) the following snag I'm experiencing in Windows 10, please?
While I originally thought this was, maybe, a problem with the source images, I'm now focusing on a difficulty with the `fifo` function – but I'm prepared to stand corrected.

*Problem*
I'm losing all but the last seventeen frames out of thirty-eight 1920x1080px frame slideshow while using the following command to create an animated gif:

```
    ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i PREFIX_%4d.png -filter_complex "scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2,split=2[palette_in][gif];[palette_in]palettegen[palette_out];[gif]fifo[gif_fifo]; [gif_fifo][palette_out]paletteuse"  -r 1 -y PREFIX.gif
```

The intention is to split the input, create a palette  and then use this to create the output gif. Why? Because `StackExchange` taught me to do it this way.

the `PREFIX_????.png` fileset is a sequentially numbered copy of an original jpg photo sequence.
Frame loss is consistent over many runs with this image set, including using the 'original' first-pass copy pngs (with non-sequentially numbered file names) specified in a concat file with a 1.0 second duration parameter.

*Basic Output*

```
ffmpeg version N-94174-gfeade2b403 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 56.100 /  7. 56.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, image2, from 'PREFIX_%4d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:38.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 16:9], 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> scale
  paletteuse -> Stream #0:0 (gif)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, gif, to 'PREFIX.gif':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, pal8, 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1 fps, 100 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.53.101 gif
[Parsed_palettegen_2 @ 0000023393365180] 255(+1) colors generated out of 492243 colors; ratio=0.000518
frame=   17 fps=2.9 q=-0.0 Lsize=    6098kB time=00:00:37.01 bitrate=1349.8kbits/s speed=6.21x
video:6098kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000320%
```

The problem has not manifested on other test image sets and does not manifest if the split/fifo/palette section is removed.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i PREFIX_%4d.png  -r 1 -y PREFIX.gif
```

The scaling filter was included as a test only, although it does help keep the test gif size down!

Comment: Share full log for `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i PREFIX_%4d.png -filter_complex "scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2,split=2[palette_in][gif];[palette_in]palettegen,showinfo@pg[palette_out];[gif]fifo[gif_fifo]; [gif_fifo][palette_out]paletteuse,showinfo@pu"  -r 1 -y PREFIX.gif`

Comment: Use the command I provided.

Comment: [You Know How It Is When You Can't Be Bothered To Read Every Bracket Any More](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bJ6SQ5AWjHV7i1zhh9ObYIT-cKpeJcMr)

Comment: Can't reproduce it here with version N-94391. Upgrade and check.

Comment: As I've said, it doesn't reproduce well.

ffmpeg version N-94396-g47b6ca0b02: same thing as ever.

I was wondering if the volume of data was breaking the fifo buffer. Not that that 'should' be a problem.

back later

Comment: Can you share this image set?

Comment: It's proprietary, sadly, which is one reason I was trying to reproduce the result to share here.

Comment: Ok, rerun with `showinfo@pg` shifted to before palettegen and `showinfo@ff` added after fifo.

Comment: [showinfo@pg,palettegen...fifo,showinfo@pg logfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14aDcLQfZyFEGKcdeSr1B7R1DkIBD505Q)
However.
I've duplicated the result: several of the original sequence were edited in Gimp 2.10.x and exported to png to be substituted into the gif; everything between frame 1 and the last Gimped frame is excluded.
ffprobe gives this for the 'original' images
 `Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 5312x2988, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc`
and
 `Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 5312x2988 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc`
for the Gimped images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most filters in ffmpeg require the input to have consistent attributes across all frames of the input. Only a few filters are coded to be aware of and adjust to changing attributes (scale being one of them).

The logs shows that the filtergraph is reinitialized twice at the 15th and 22nd frames implying some attribute inconsistency. Need more logging to identify what those are. When reinitialized, the fifo filter loses all frames buffered before reinitialization, hence the frame losses.

Try

```
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -framerate 1 -i PREFIX_%4d.png -filter_complex "scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2,format=bgra,split=2[palette_in][gif];[palette_in]palettegen[palette_out];[gif]fifo[gif_fifo]; [gif_fifo][palette_out]paletteuse"  -r 1 -y PREFIX.gif
```

The `-reinit_filter 0` tells ffmpeg to skip reinitialization. The scale and format at the front of the filtergraph ensure* that all further filters receive uniform input.

*sort of. The scale args should be set to fixed sizes to be sure of that. In this case, I believe the pixel format has changed and the format filter takes care of that.

Comment: This command produces the desired output.
Can you add a brief explanation  for other readers of the analysis which lead to this result?

Comment: Can you comment on the following showinfo message:
`side data - unknown side data type 15 (672 bytes)`  

"side data" is not an obvious term to research

Comment: Sometimes there is auxiliary data attached with the media content e.g. timecode or orientation info. They aren't part of the raw media data, so In ffmpeg parlance, these are called side data. That message shows some side data that ffmpeg does not recognize.

Comment: Thank you.

I see that there are several areas of difference between the Gimped files and the default,including suggested print-resolution data, an alpha channel and exif and icc data.
Do you have any suggestions as to how to work out which – if any – ffmpeg isn't accessing sensibly so that with can be logged with either ffmpeg or gimp devs?